# How to change html of the layout from a view that uses it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Lets say I have `_Layout.cshtml` where I have this:

```
 @if (ViewBag.SignUpURL == null)
        {   
            <a href="@Url.Content("~/Home/Join")" ><span>
                <strong>JOIN NOW!</strong></span></a>
        }
        else
        {         
            <a href="@ViewBag.SignUpURL" ><span>
                <strong>JOIN NOW!</strong></span></a>
        }
```

When I try to populate `ViewBag.SignUpURL` under

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.SignUpURL = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("Index", "SignUp");

            return View();
        }
```

`Index` view uses `_Layout.cshtml`.

And nothing happens...

In general I need somehow **pass** data to `Layout` page from page that uses it.

Is it possible to do?

THANK YOU!!!

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's supposed to work. Are you sure `HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` isn't somehow raising an exception that's handled elsewhere causing `ViewBag.SignUpURL` to be null?

Comment: @David Put it like an answer... Damn it! I have used other _Layout page... It is working as u said... HA :)

Comment: Why not just use the Html.ActionLink helper in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using Html.RenderAction()  which will then go back to controller action that you specify, and you'll be able to return a partial view with a model for it:

View:

```
@Html.RenderAction("GetSignUp")
```

Controller action

```
public ActionResult GetSignUp()
{
//do your logic here

    return PartialView("_SignUp");
}
```

Comment: No no I need to use somehow TempData or ViwBag or at least I can use Session object to pass data to the 'Layout page' and change html there. I just tried to use ViewBag and it is not working... I gussed it MUST....

Comment: This is what I'd vote for less doing a RenderAction just to perform a request for a partial view. I'd personally just add a @Html.Partial("_TestPartialView") right in your _layout page. There's really no logic involved here other than setting a viewbag property which can be done in any action....Update to Peretz: He's not saying to not use ViewBag. He's just reorganizing your logic to have this in it's own partial view. I wrote a 2 minute test case and what bobek suggests does work.

Comment: @Khepri Cool... But still... I am sure that I assign correct value to ViewBag and I am guessing to use it at  Layout Page... but no success.. Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: Have you tried his suggestion of adding a partial view and rendering that in the _layout page? Either way works so the only other thing I can think of is that you are overwriting the viewbag value somewhere else.

Comment: It isn't the best practice to use ViewBag. It's much nicer and cleaner if you have a ViewModel with properties on it and then return it to a View. However, as you guys point out, both solutions will work.

Answer (score 1):

All is good. You can use ViewBag to pass some data to Layout. 
But I think that `HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` doesn't contain `Index` because of the routing rule.

Comment: Thank for the input! I am sure I have it there 1) I have special routes 2) I have debugged it. So it is there....

Comment: @Peretz and which value of ViewBag.SignUpURL do you have on the layout? null?

Comment: @Peretz do you use it somewhere else? maybe you overwrite the value in another place?